# Not able to run skip Cucumber tests on tags on command line. getting must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix >

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit

Any help on what should i do to run the command line for skipping Cucumber tags?  i have tried various ways (https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/cucumber-skip-test-command-line)but each way i get the below error for the mvn command. Would i need to configure anything for cucumber to run the -Dcucumber.options flag? please help

```
XX@DESKTOP-R87G978 MINGW64 ~/Downloads/sample/task (main)
$ mvn -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@smoke'"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.367 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-06T13:25:53Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

This is my Pom.xml for build configuration

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/com/example/demo</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>frontend</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty much self explanatory. While you have specified the option indeed you forgot to set the goal or a phase which are actually and instruction for the maven for what to do.

Like

`mvn -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@smoke'" test` where `test` is the phase.